# Data Access Object or Inline Methods

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sqlite, air, data-access

I am still very new to Actionscript and have an okay working knowledge of Flex.  I am working on an AIR application that runs a SQLite database underneath.  The database is only 3 tables (projects, items and types).  I was wondering if Actionscript best practices are to use a data access object or layer to store all of my database functions or to just run them inline as needed.  I would assume an access layer would be best for interacting with the database for usability, but I can't seem to find much documentation for SQLite in AIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on the complexity of your application, but in general I would propose using an abstraction over the database access. The key is to create an interface that your application will talk to and then provide a SQLite implementation. The benefit is that you can easily create a stub or mock implementation for testing and you can create new implementation that talk to other technologies. The [Spring ActionScript](http://www.springactionscript.org) framework has some good utilities to achieve this.

I responded to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825460/working-with-both-adobe-flex-web-and-desktop-application/4826098#4826098).

Comment: Thanks Christophe, I will look at the Spring ActionScript framework.